# Jquery Mobile dynamic thumbnail list-How to create a border?

Tags: css, listview, jquery-mobile, border, thumbnails

I've searched and searched. I can't find an answer to what I think must be fairly easy to accomplish. I have a jquery mobile listview that is populated by a spry dataset. I load thumbnail images dynamically from the spry dataset. I'd like to create a border around each thumbnail using css/html. I've tried a number of different approaches.

The only one that works so far is to redraw every image with a border in Fireworks or a similar graphics program. A lot of extra work for something that I'm sure is simple for a more knowledgeable person.

Can anyone give me a little help with how to place a border around a thumbnail in a list that is populated by a dataset?

Comment: Can you supply the HTML markup or at least the outputted markup? Just need a little more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery Mobile has a CSS rule that sets border-width for all images inside a link to 0. To have borders on listview thumbnails, you need to override the border-width and then set the border color and style:

```
.ui-li-thumb {
    border-width: 2px !important;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your overriding stylesheet:

```
.ui-li-thumb { border: 2px solid #000 !important; }
```

Comment: Does your image have a class associated to it?